# How to return a python datetime format string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I would like to have the following funcitonality `some_function('2018-06-05 00:00:00')` and it should return `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` which is the format of the input date.

Is there a function in `dateutils.parser` or in some other library that I can use?